# Why can I not use as-cast to convert `object` to an enum type?

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, prism

When you implement `ICommand` you have to implement the `public void Execute(object parameters)` method, which takes parameters of type `object`.

For my specific application I'm interested in how I can implement an `ICommand` which takes an enum as parameter.

In my command I implement `Execute` like this:

```cs
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
  if (parameter is null) throw new ArgumentNullException("parameter");
  State s = parameter as State;
  }
```

where `State` is my enum type defined as

```cs
public enum State
{
  NeutralState,
  MeasureCircleState,
  MeasureSphereState  
}
```

Unfortunately my IDE flags my code, specifically the line
`State s = parameter as State;` as invalid.

What is wrong with my code?
Can I not convert my `object parameter` to my enum type `State`?

Comment: "However you can not cast object to an enum type that easily. " - I can, actually. `if (parameter is State state) { /* do word */ } else { /* throw exception*/ }`

Comment: Thanks to both of you for giving this much inside and information. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

object parameter can be converted to enum:

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter is State s)
    {
       // do work;
    }
    else
    {
         throw new ArgumentException(nameof(parameter));
    }
}
```

you should also pass it correctly from XAML, e.g:

```
CommandParameter="{x:Static local:State.NeutralState}"
```

and not just `CommandParameter="NeutralState"`, which will pass a string

Comment: IMO better: `if (!(parameter is State s)) { throw ... } // do work without else`

Comment: You're right. You can cast it!
I didn't know the `if (parameter is State s) { ... }` syntax. But also `State s =(State)parameter;` seems to work. Which had me confused at the time of posting my question is that `State s = parameter as State;` is not allowed. That hat me assume that casts between those types in general don't work. Thank you.

Comment: `State s = parameter as State;` is not allowed because `as` works with reference types only. enum is a value type. `State s =(State)parameter;` works if and only if parameter is State value. for null and any other type it will crash with InvalidCastException